# Стили в битриксе откатываются до предыдущих значений

Tags: битрикс

Меняю стили в шаблонах bitrix, они применяются, но спустя не долгое время откатываются до прежних значений, при чём в плане отображения, а в шаблонах они сохраняют нужное значение, а система подгружает старые стили из кэша. Пробовал удалять всё, что лежит в папке bitrix/cache, пробовал просто нажать на кнопку "Сбросить кэш", не помогает. Как можно его очистить полностью?

Comment: Стили не связаны с кнопкой "Сбросить кеш". Здесь кеш браузера, или CDN-кеш, или еще что-то. Попробуйте воспроизвести проблему, и после этого нажать на странице Ctrl-F5, стили станут актуальными?

Comment: К сожалению не стали.. Самое странное то, что сначала стили применились, и спустя минут 20 они стали старыми, хотя файл со стилями никто не трогал

Comment: Здесь нужно отслеживать ситуацию через инструменты разработчика - смотреть как он загружает нужный файл стилей, и какой контент отдается в этом файле. В общем, процесс отладки не очень простой, но других нормальных вариантов нет.

Comment: понял, спасибо) буду разбираться